# Service(logstash) doesn't start when using Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, logstash, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I've got an issue with Chef recipe that I wrote to install and configure logstash. Installation and creating config file is working, but when I'm trying to start, stop, restart service in recipe, example:

```
service 'logstash' do
  action :start
end
```

it doesn't restart the service, however if I log into the machine, I can use

```
sudo service logstash start
```

and it works correctly.

I already checked two similar threads but didn't found the solution to this problem.

Maybe anyone has an idea what might be causing it ?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I've tried in on Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian Jessie.

Comment: Set the provider to upstart explicitly? The autodetection can get wonky sometimes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that ? It's quite weird because with Elasticsearch, Kibana, nginx everything works fine.

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same exact problem

Comment: Hey @NickGinanto, sorry that late reply, I didn't solve this, at least not properly. For now I used a workaround where I execute `sudo service logstash start` as a shell command from Chef (ugly but it works).

Answer (score 0):

If it is running with direct sudo command then, probably it has to do either with environment variables setting between "root" user and the user as which you are starting the service. If possible please check and share the same.